# How to make a control snap to a Grid.Row/Grid.Column in WPF at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a grid with some ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions. What I like to do is drag a control at runtime and have it snap to a given GridColumn/GridRow when the control is over that GridColumn/GridRow. I was not able to find any resources on this. Perhaps I am using the wrong key words. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should extend Grid. Then on drop check the location and add the dropped element to the respective cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend `Grid` to handle the drop position. Let the `Grid` add the dropped element to the appropriate cell.

The following simple but working example shows how to enable dragging of any `UIElement` from a `Panel` such as `StackPanel` or `Grid` to the custom `DrockingGrid`.
The custom Grid simply overrides the relevant drag&drop overrides. It's a minimal but working example, therefore only `OnDragEnter` and `OnDrop` are overridden.

On drop, you basically have to identify the cell the element was dropped in by using the drop position from the `DragEventArgs`. Then remove the dropped element from its original parent container (where the drag operation has started) and then insert it into the `DockingGrid`. You then use `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` to position the element in the appropriate cell:

**DockingGrid.cs**

```
public class DockingGrid : Grid
{
  private bool AcceptsDrop { get; set; }
  private Brush OriginalBackgroundBrush { get; set; }

  public DockingGrid()
  {
    this.AllowDrop = true;
  }

  protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnDragEnter(e);
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    this.AcceptsDrop = e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(UIElement));

    if (this.AcceptsDrop)
    {
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
      ShowDropTargetEffects();
    }
  }

  protected override void OnDragLeave(DragEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnDragEnter(e);
    ClearDropTargetEffects();
  }

  protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnDrop(e);
    if (!this.AcceptsDrop)
    {
      return;
    }

    ClearDropTargetEffects();

    var droppedElement = e.Data.GetData(typeof(UIElement)) as UIElement;
    RemoveDroppedElementFromDragSourceContainer(droppedElement);
    _ = this.Children.Add(droppedElement);

    Point dropPosition = e.GetPosition(this);
    SetColumn(droppedElement, dropPosition.X);
    SetRow(droppedElement, dropPosition.Y);
  }

  private void SetRow(UIElement? droppedElement, double verticalOffset)
  {
    double totalRowHeight = 0;
    int targetRowIndex = 0;
    foreach (RowDefinition? rowDefinition in this.RowDefinitions)
    {
      totalRowHeight += rowDefinition.ActualHeight;
      if (totalRowHeight >= verticalOffset)
      {
        Grid.SetRow(droppedElement, targetRowIndex);
        break;
      }

      targetRowIndex++;
    }
  }

  private void SetColumn(UIElement? droppedElement, double horizontalOffset)
  {
    double totalColumnWidth = 0;
    int targetColumntIndex = 0;
    foreach (ColumnDefinition? columnDefinition in this.ColumnDefinitions)
    {
      totalColumnWidth += columnDefinition.ActualWidth;
      if (totalColumnWidth >= horizontalOffset)
      {
        Grid.SetColumn(droppedElement, targetColumntIndex);
        break;
      }

      targetColumntIndex++;
    }
  }

  private void RemoveDroppedElementFromSourceContainer(UIElement droppedElement)
  {
    DependencyObject parent = droppedElement is FrameworkElement frameworkElement
      ? frameworkElement.Parent
      : VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(droppedElement);

    if (parent is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    switch (parent)
    {
      case Panel panel:
        panel.Children.Remove(droppedElement);
        break;
      case ContentControl contentControl:
        contentControl.Content = null;
        break;
      case ContentPresenter contentPresenter:
        contentPresenter.Content = null;
        droppedElement.UpdateLayout();
        break;
      case Decorator decorator:
        decorator.Child = null;
        break;
      default:
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Parent type {parent.GetType()} not supported");
    }
  }

  private void ShowDropTargetEffects()
  {
    this.ShowGridLines = true;
    this.OriginalBackgroundBrush = this.Background;
    this.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
  }

  private void ClearDropTargetEffects()
  {
    this.Background = this.OriginalBackgroundBrush;
    this.ShowGridLines = false;
  }
}
```

### Usage

Use it like a normal `Grid`.
Now the user can drag any control into any of the predefined cells.

```xml
<local:DockingGrid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    <RowDefinition Height="300" />
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</local:DockingGrid>
```

In the parent host of the drag&drop context for example the Window, enable/start the drag behavior:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed
      && e.Source is UIElement uIElement)
    {
      _ = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(uIElement, new DataObject(typeof(UIElement), uIElement), DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
  }
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs: Drag and Drop Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to learn more about the feature.

Comment: Works great! Quick question would it be possible to show the control moving as it being dragged? Or do you need to have a canvas to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to put that control inside something which fills that cell.  You could just put it in that grid cell by adding it to the grid children and setting grid row and column attached properties but there is a gotcha.

A grid cell is sort of conceptual.

The grid looks at it's content, looks at it's definitions for rows and columns and works out where to put it's content using measure arrange passes.

Which is a wordy way of saying there's nothing there to drag your control into.

You need a drop target to drag drop anything into.  As it's name suggests, you need some sort of a receptacle for the thing you are dragging.

Wpf, however has these things called content controls.

A button actually inherits from content control to allow it to have things like a string in it.

There is also a content control itself.  Which is just kind of like a receptacle for something or other.

One of these things can be used in a given cell as a sort of a place holder. And then you have something in a cell that you can drop into.

I think if you just throw a contentcontrol in a grid without anything inside it you might have problems hit testing.

Some experimentation in a scratch project is advisable.

But basically you could have something like:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Fill="Red"
                   Name="DraggAbleThing"
                   MouseMove="DraggAbleThing_MouseMove"
                   />
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        x:Name="BottomRight"
                        AllowDrop="True"
                        >
            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow"/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

There's a fair bit to implement in order to do drag drop but the idea here is you have something in the bottom right cell which you can drop into. You might have to set ishitestable=false on that yellow rectangle.

I'd have to implement all the drag drop methods to try it out.

If I did and drop works ok then when the contentcontrol gets draggablething dropped into it.

Set the content property of the contentcontrol to draggablething and it is now in the bottom right cell.

It will fill that cell because the grid arranges it's contents to fill whichever logical cell it decides they're "in".

Answer (score 1):

I would like to present an example I wrote that is working.
In the Application I wrote I have a Grid with 4 Rows and 4 Columns.
I can place in each Cell a different UserControl that is based on a class I called
BaseDragDropUserControl:

```
public class BaseDragDropUserControl: UserControl
    {
        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DataObject data = new DataObject();
                data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, nameof(BaseDragDropUserControl));
                BaseDragDropUserControl tobemMoved = (BaseDragDropUserControl)e.Source;
                int row = (int)tobemMoved.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
                int col = (int)tobemMoved.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
                data.SetData("Source", tobemMoved);
                data.SetData("Row", row);
                data.SetData("Col", col);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnGiveFeedback(GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnGiveFeedback(e);
            
            if (e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Copy))
            {
                Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Cross);
            }
            else if (e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move))
            {
                Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Pen);
            }
            else
            {
                Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.No);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDrop(e);

            // If the DataObject contains string data, extract it.
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
            {
                string dataString = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
                if (dataString == nameof(BaseDragDropUserControl))
                {
                    int targetRow = (int)this.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
                    int targetCol = (int)this.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
                    int originRow = (int)e.Data.GetData("Row");
                    int originCol = (int)e.Data.GetData("Col");
                    BaseDragDropUserControl origin = (BaseDragDropUserControl)e.Data.GetData("Source");
                    this.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, originRow);
                    this.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, originCol);
                    origin.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, targetRow);
                    origin.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, targetCol);
                }
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

The above class is the "Heavy one". It handle both the Drag and the Drop functions.
It ships data object with the origin UserControl and also intercept it when it is dropped. It switch the Grid.Row and Grid.Column values between the origin UserControl and the Target UserControl. In doing this the locations are changed.

I created 2 UsserControls.
RedUserControl and BlueUserControl:

```
<local:BaseDragDropUserControl x:Class="Problem10.RedUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Problem10"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</local:BaseDragDropUserControl>


<local:BaseDragDropUserControl x:Class="Problem10.BlueUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Problem10"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
    </Grid>
</local:BaseDragDropUserControl>
```

The MainWindow is as following:

```
<Grid  >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:RedUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <local:RedUserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <local:RedUserControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <local:RedUserControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <local:BlueUserControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Application is ready for you ! Come and play.